# How do I manually invoke the Java Validation API?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, annotations

Is there any particulars on when to use the annotations in java, or to put it more precisely, is the answer to the following question Yes or No

> Only under **this** condition, can this particular annotations be used.

Obviously, the **this** in the above statement can be anything or nothing.

The reason I ask this question is that I was given this code base and in their they had used some annotations to validate the classes, properties etc. Now, this is a web application and it makes use of all the spring beans and what not.

I tried the following code. (This is just normal java code, no spring or anything.This is the entire code)

```
public class AnnotationsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TestMe t = new TestMe();
        System.out.println(t.getTest1());

    }

}

class TestMe{
    @NotNull
    private String test1;

    public String getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }

    public void setTest1(String test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }
}
```

This one prints out **null** as output. Why is not any validation happening?

Well, what I am guessing is that I've provided the annotations for this, but have not really validated.  So I went to [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-gettingstarted.html). Therein he had all sorts of `ValidationFactory` and what not.

So I wrote,

```
public class AnnotationsTest{

    private static Validator validator;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = factory.getValidator();
            TestMe t = new TestMe();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<TestMe>> constraintViolations =
                validator.validate(t);

            assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
            assertEquals("may not be null", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());

    }
}
```

But this one give the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at AnnotationsTest.main(AnnotationsTest.java:29)
```

So here's my questions:
 1. What exactly happened in the two cases above?
 2. I thought that annotations were enough, as in `Autowired` and stuff, they would just inject the classes on it's own. But here why do I need to do the extra stuff to validate. Why doesnt `@NotNull` validates the things on it's own.

Thanks.

Comment: javax.validation... Is just an API. You need also an implementation like Hibernate-Validator. This should fix the not found issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to understand about annotations is they are just metadata on code. Nothing more, nothing less.

In order for all the black magic to happen (in your case Validation, or in the case of `@Autowired` as you mentioned the registering into the Spring container), some other piece of code needs to read the class definitions, check and see if the annotations are present and if so, perform a while bunch of steps (which may include simple things like registering objects or more advanced things like creating proxies, manipulating bytecode etc.).

So in your case, although the metadata is present on the class in the form of annotations, however no code is present that actually handles them. In the case of validation, that code would be Hibernate Validator.

In order to use Hibernate Validator you could check out [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator) link

Comment: Ohh, so even if I get the implementation of the specs, ie the Hibernate Validator, the first piece of code wont work right? It will still print null and not really validate.

Comment: Exacly! You need to register Hibernate Validator with your application and make it run the validation. What Hibernate Validator does is actually handle the nuts and bolts of validation. You are the one that actually has to tell it make it do all that (in a standalone environment, in a Spring environment Spring can invoke the validation for you)

Comment: I am sorry, but I think I am still not sure what is wrong with the second code? I just took it from the link that is given? And I am not sure why is it not working

Comment: Are you sure that Hibernate Validator is on your classpath?

Comment: But yeah, why is that requried. Initially I thought that Validation was an interface and Hibernate Validator may be the implementation that is required for it. But now I see that Validation is a class and if I call a method on it, it should fetch me the validator right?

Comment: Yeah, now I have the hibernate-validator and the error is not there. But I am not sure what exactly has hibernate-validator provided, that wasnt there beforehand.

Comment: The issue is this: validation-api.xxx.jar provides the interfaces for validation to take place. `Validator` is an interface in that jar as are more interfaces in that api jar. hibernate-validator.xxx.jar provides the implementation for those interfaces amongst which is `ValidatorImpl` for `Validator`

Comment: Yeah, `Validator` is an interface, but `Validation` is not right? And Validation has a function that is `buildDefaultValidatorFactory().` And this method is causing the exception. Are you saying that within this method, there'd be a reference to `Validator` and that is when the exception occurs?


Also, how is it that when I put Hibernate-Validator in the everything works fine. I get it that Hibernate-Validator provides the implementation for all the methods in the interface. But where how does the compiler knows that it must look into Hibernate-Validator for the implementation? continued ....

Comment: I have not actually checked the source code, but my best guess is that the code in Validation checks the classpath to see if there is an implementation of Validator anywhere on the classpath. That is a pretty standard technique used in production grade frameworks

Comment: For all I know, if there was a class `Parent` and it had an abstract function `P()` and I provided the definition of the function in another class `Child()`, then I can substitute the parent with child, while calling method `P()` but also in that case I do.  `Parent p = new Child(); and p.P();  ` ie I pass the reference and that is how the code knows to take the child's implementation. But just putting the class on the classpath, how does the compiler knows where to get the implementation from?

Comment: The compiler has nothing to do with where the implementation is found. The framework uses some classloader black magic to find the implementation at runtime!

Comment: Ohk, Thanks. I think i get it.